# Getting both listbox text and value in server handler

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the following code where I try to fill a listbox with the addItem(text,value) method to store both a text and an index and I would like to retriebe both when the listbox is clicked.
As a default e.parameter.listObject returns the text. Is there anyway to retriebe also the value?

The code is as follows:

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('New app');

  var listHandler = app.createServerKeyHandler('listSelect');
  var lb = app.createListBox(true).setId('lbColour').setName('lbColour').setVisibleItemCount(10).addClickHandler(listHandler);  

  lb.addItem("RED","100");
  lb.addItem("GREEN","010");
  lb.addItem("BLUE","001");

  // Create a vertical panel and add the grid to the panel
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  panel.setId('mainPanel');
  panel.add(lb);  
  panel.add(app.createLabel('Colour Code:'));
  panel.add(app.createTextBox().setName('colourCode').setId('colourCode'));
  panel.add(app.createLabel('Colour Name:'));
  panel.add(app.createTextBox().setName('colourName').setId('colourName'));
  app.add(panel);
  return app;
}

function listSelect(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.getElementById('colourName').setText(e.parameter.lbColour);
  app.getElementById('colourCode').setText(e.parameter['lbColour_Value']);
  return(app);
}
```

Thanks to the below answers this will be the corrected code for the above one.

Note that as stated we can store the key at the text property using a valid separator, I used here "|" which is not as usual to find in an string as ",".

Also note that the main to problems on the original code for this to work was that the lisbox cannot be created as a multiselect, that is:

1. We shall use "createListBox()" instead of "createListBox(true)"
2. The server handler shall be created using "createServerHandler" instead of "creteServerKeyHandler".

The final code should look like this:

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('New app');

  var listHandler = app.createServerHandler('listSelect');
  var lb = app.createListBox().setId('lbColour').setName('lbColour').setVisibleItemCount(10).addClickHandler(listHandler);  

  lb.addItem("RED","RED|100");
  lb.addItem("GREEN","GREEN|010");
  lb.addItem("BLUE","BLUE|001");

  // Create a vertical panel and add the grid to the panel
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  panel.setId('mainPanel');
  panel.add(lb);  
  panel.add(app.createLabel('Colour Code:'));
  panel.add(app.createTextBox().setName('colourCode').setId('colourCode'));
  panel.add(app.createLabel('Colour Name:'));
  panel.add(app.createTextBox().setName('colourName').setId('colourName'));
  app.add(panel);
  return app;
}

function listSelect(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var outpArr = e.parameter.lbColour.split('|');  
  app.getElementById('colourName').setText(outpArr[0]);
  app.getElementById('colourCode').setText(outpArr[1]);
  return(app);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't retrieve the text of your list box item.
What you can do is this,

Reformat your list items like this:

```
lb.addItem("BLUE","001,BLUE");
```

And then

```
e.parameter.lbColour.split(',')[0]
```

Will return 001
And

```
e.parameter.lbColour.split(',')[1]
```

Will return BLUE

Good luck

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var vp = app.createVerticalPanel().setId("vp");
  var lb = app.createListBox().setName("lb");
  lb.addItem("BLUE", "BLUE,001");
  vp.add(lb);

  var handler = app.createServerHandler('postFunc').addCallbackElement(vp);
  var button = app.createButton("Send").addClickHandler(handler);
  vp.add(button);

  app.add(vp);
  return app;
}

function postFunc(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  var vp = app.getElementById("vp");
  var outpArr = e.parameter.lb.split(',');
  var color = app.createLabel("color text: " + outpArr[0]);
  var number = app.createLabel("color number: " + outpArr[1]);

  vp.add(color);
  vp.add(number);

  return app;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work since the returned value is the (shown) text value... !! so you should use lb.addItem("RED,100") but this is not very nice looking...

Comment: No the return value is not the text value. lb.addItem("BLUE","001,BLUE"); will return a string: 001,BLUE and the shown text is: BLUE if you split the output string you can get the individual value. If you need it as int use ParseInt. This is the only way

Comment: I tested your solution before writing my comment... I regret to say you're wrong. Have you tested it yourself?  The value returned by your code is the text value, the result cannot be splitted.

Comment: Serge is right! on his comment, any other Idea? I cannot imaging why it is possible to differenciate between addItem(text) and addItem(text, value) when you cannot evaluate value in a handler...

Comment: Don't tell me im wrong! i posted an example in this Post. And i've done this in a live application before.

Comment: Your problem is the handler your using. When u use the onclick handler on a listbox the value will not be send to your function what you want to use is the change handler. Ill post an example.

Comment: ok, sorry about that... I didn't check the handler... but you are still not 100% right since a click handler does the job. see edit. Anyway, no bad feelings, cheers

Comment: My apologies to Thomas and thanks also to Serge. It looks like the aproach from Thomas was not working due to the fact that the listbox was created as a multiselect and also that the server handler was created as a KeyServerHandler. I have updated my question with a working version of the original code. Again many thanks for your support to both of you.

Comment: Well we actually still have a problem... If you do a select box with multi select you can not get the value only the name. I haven't found an issue about that in the issue tracker. I think we need to post this because it should work.

Comment: You're right, I'll post it on the issue tracker with demo code. thanks for the heads up ;)

Comment: Ooops... already there : [issue 941](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=941)

Comment: I posted a possible workaround here and on issue 941. sorry for being so long in these comments ;-)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT 2 : Thomas's answer wasn't wrong after all... The handler used in the original question was the cause of the issue and the multiple selection enable suffers also of an issue -see last comments ([issue 941](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=941)).

So I removed my first answer (to make it shorter) and suggest here a possible workaround to use multiple selection on a listBox (tested and working)

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('New app');

  var listHandler = app.createServerHandler('listSelect');
  var lb = app.createListBox(true).setWidth('200').setId('lbColour').setName('lbColour').setVisibleItemCount(5).addChangeHandler(listHandler);  
 var colorIndex = [];// this is the array that will hold item values values with 2 fields
  lb.addItem("RED");colorIndex.push("RED-100");// use a '-' separator to be able to split later First field-second field
  lb.addItem("GREEN");colorIndex.push("GREEN-010");
  lb.addItem("BLUE");colorIndex.push("BLUE-001");

  lb.setTag(colorIndex.toString());// store the array in the TAG
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  panel.setId('mainPanel');
  panel.add(lb);  
  panel.add(app.createLabel('Colour Code:'));
  panel.add(app.createTextBox().setWidth('500').setName('colourCode').setId('colourCode'));
  panel.add(app.createLabel('Colour Name:'));
  panel.add(app.createTextBox().setWidth('500').setName('colourName').setId('colourName'));
  app.add(panel);
  return app;
}

function listSelect(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var codepos = [];//will get the index position of items in colorIndex
  var code = [];//array of first items found in colorIndex
  var color = [];// index of second items found in colorIndex
  var colorIndex = e.parameter.lbColour_tag.split(',');// recover the array
  for(n=0;n<colorIndex.length;++n){if(e.parameter.lbColour.match(colorIndex[n].split('-')[0]) == colorIndex[n].split('-')[0]){codepos.push(n)}};// get the position in the array
  for(n=0;n<codepos.length;++n){
  code[n] = colorIndex[codepos[n]].split('-')[1];// finally get the color code value
  color[n] = colorIndex[codepos[n]].split('-')[0];// get the color value
}  
  app.getElementById('colourName').setText(color.toString());// show the result second field
  app.getElementById('colourCode').setText(code.toString()); // show the result first field
  return(app);
}
```