# GAS: How to set listbox selection to shown value

Tags: google-apps-script

I have sorted my listbox values ascending and selected for example the 3rd value. After the selection,the value shown in the listbox is the first one. It should be the selected value, not the first value. Is it possible to "activate" the selected value to be shown after it is selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This not a normal behavior ... if you select an item in a listBox it shows the selected item....
could you post the code you are using so we can try to reproduce the issue ?

Comment: I figured out where the problem was. I have stored the values in database using UI and because I wanted the listbox be uptodate when I click it I coded the update routine in the listbox handler function. Now I removed it to Add and Delete routines and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have struggled with this over the past few days and came across a few difficulties. For a listbox (lb), an array of items and a selected item in the list (setitem) the following rather inelegant code works in a dropdown (single selection) listbox with just the labels (no values) and number of displayed values set to 1. Changing any of those conditions seems to change behaviour markedly.

```
function fillListBox(lb,items,setitem){
    try {
      lb.clear();  // making the widget reusable

      for (j=0;j<items.length;j++){
        var item = items[j];
        lb.addItem(item);
           if (item==setitem){
          lb.setSelectedIndex(j);  // zero is the first item in list
             } 
      }

    } 
    catch(e) {
    }
  }
```

a clear documentation of this whole area would be appreciated (and better code)

Comment: I'm a bit surprised by what you say here... I've personally never experience any issue with listBoxes except the one mentioned in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12901023/getting-both-listbox-text-and-value-in-server-handler)  In what situation have you had these problems ?

Comment: my problems were similar and due to sparse documentation which drives you to explore what happens and then code around that ending up with code that works rather than the optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

While DavidF's solution works, I think this is a little simpler:

```
function fillListBox(lb,items,setitem){
  try {
    lb.clear();  // making the widget reusable

    for (j = 0; j < items.length; j++){
      lb.addItem(items[j]);
    }
    lb.setSelectedIndex(items.indexOf(setitem));
  } catch(e) {}
}
```

This way, you add all the items, and then set the index using it's index in the array.

Comment: thanks I wasn't thinking straight. was locked into the idea that I should be able to use the array on items in the widget